# Rendering non-HDR swapchain over HDR video swapchain

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, hdr

Been trying to figure this out for a while and according to the docs, this should "just work".

The setup is:

We have a video swapchain at the bottom:

```
winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaEngineEx> mediaEngineEx = m_mediaEngine.as<IMFMediaEngineEx>();
THROW_IF_FAILED(mediaEngineEx->EnableWindowlessSwapchainMode(true));

THROW_IF_FAILED(mediaEngineEx->GetVideoSwapchainHandle(&m_dcompSurfaceHandle));
```

This video can display both SDR and HDR video.

If the device and screen can support HDR, we change the display setting to HDR at startup.

Then we want to render some info on top of the video (subtitles, UI etc). Our vertex data has premultiplied alpha (this might be the issue since I haven't seen this being used in examples).

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {0};

swapChainDesc.Width = lround(m_d3dRenderTargetSize.Width);
swapChainDesc.Height = lround(m_d3dRenderTargetSize.Height);
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;

ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain3> spSwapChain3;
m_swapChain.As<IDXGISwapChain3>(&spSwapChain3);

if( FAILED(spSwapChain3->SetColorSpace1(DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709)) )
{
    FATAL("Could not set the correct color space\n");
}
```

Blending is:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc = {};
blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = false;
blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = false;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = true;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_DEST_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
DX_CHECK(s_device->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &m_blendSrcOverState));
```

The issue is when a semi-transparent gradient or box is shown over the video. The gradient gets a lot of banding and is a lot brighter than it should be. If the device is not in HDR more, it looks normal.

What am I missing here? I'm happy to provide more data. Cheers!

Comment: What is the reason to use SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_ONE instead of SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_COLOR? Can you post the onscreen image?

Comment: @DamirTenishev it's because we are using premultiplied alpha. I will try to create something that I can post. But if you have a 50% alpha black overlay, it just because a lot brighter. If you have a semi-transparent gradient, it gets a lot more banding (you can see 20-30 seperate bands, despite added noise).

Comment: Have I had the project to run and check, I would join to investigation; could you share somewhere (github?) the minimal reproducible project?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Hi, I'm really sorry but it's part of a pretty large codebase. Most of the code is pretty standard though (using MS examples). The issue is basically how to blend and non-HDR swapchain onto a HDR one. All the docs just says to define the color format etc, but it doesn't really work. I am starting to think it might be the premultiplied alpha that is the issue here.

Comment: So, what is in your way to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would be much easier to help having a point to start and see the issue.

Comment: @DamirTenishev posted an answer. Not really what I thought would fix it, but... yeah :| 
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help someone else, but what solved it in the end was something very unrelated.

```
MFARGB borderColor{ 0, 0, 0, 0 };
mediaEngineEx->UpdateVideoStream(nullptr, &destRect, &borderColor);
```

We are using the `IMFMediaEngineEx` for our HDR video, and when we set the border color, the blending seems to look more accurate.

Still trying to look into why this fixed it, because it makes no sense.